# Problem with __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, __EVENTTARGET and scrapy & splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-shell

How do i handle __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, __EVENTTARGET with scrapy/splash?

I tried with

```
return FormRequest.from_response(response,
    [...]
    '__VIEWSTATE': response.css(
    'input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a dict as the `formdata` keyword arg.

(I'd also recommend extracting into variables first for readability)

```
def parse(self, response):
    vs = response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
    ev = # another extraction
    et = # a third extraction
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'__VIEWSTATE': vs,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': ev,
            '__EVENTTARGET': et },
        callback=self.your_callback
    )
```

See [this doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=formrequest#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) for more information.